# How to play sound in default player?

Tags: android, audio

I am playing sound using Intent code. My code works perfectly fine.My device has two sound player the default one and the Google Play Music, so the issue is whenever i try to play a sound it shows me a popup to which player i want to play the sound. Below is an image of the popup.

[image]

This is my code to play sound,

```
Uri myUri =Uri.parse("file:/"+selectedFile);
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(myUri, "audio/mp3"); 
startActivity(intent);
```

I just want to play a sound in default player without showing this popup. what should i do for it ?

Comment: u can try this using  PackageManager to get default player application lunching intent

Comment: have u tried android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER action?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK, nopes, can you please post that thing in answer ?

Comment: first try it and let me known it's working or not

Comment: any success or still facing same issue?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK, i wrote this line `Intent intent = new Intent(android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER);` and it is giving me error `android.intent can not resolved to a variable`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26911/discussion-between--k-and-raynold)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to reconsider and allow both players to popup as they currently do. After all user can always check 'Use by default' if she wants to.

If you really need only the Google player then you may find what its package name is within the google sources and start its activitiy explicitly. But they can change that in future releases or maybe it's already different for different releases. Better you reconsider and allow both.