# using default media player to open stream from an Ip in android using uri

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, mime, start-activity

I'm trying open [this stream](http://iutv.iut.ac.ir:5657/tv2.flv) in my android app using the default media player but all of my media players got error (e.g. MX Player, and VLC Player).

The Code is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://iutv.iut.ac.ir:5657/tv2.flv");                      
intent.setType("video/*");
startActivity(intent)
```

And the error is :

```
VLC encountered an error with this media.
Please try refreshing the media library
```

But when I enter the link on chrome web browser it can open the link with both MX Player and VLC Player properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://iutv.iut.ac.ir:5657/tv2"), "video/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

But if your problem still occurring ,take a look at here :

[VLC encountered an error with this media Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793151/vlc-encountered-an-error-with-this-media-android)